# Validate URL's protocol identifier using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing problems in validating a URL.
This is the regular expression I used to validate the URL's protocol identifier

```
"(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)"
```

It is accepting the following URLs:

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://google.com
```

However, it is not accepting "www.google.com"
What changes do I need to made in the regular expression, to make it work ?

Comment: "www.google.com" is not a protocol. How do you get the URL and what is expected result?

Comment: A valid URL needs a protocol

Comment: ok. i want to check the URL with protocol and without protocol.. but i returns the error if i use any url with protocol identifier. that should not happen

Comment: if i get the url like "www.google.com" i ll add the "http://" dynamically but i want to check the give url  "www.google.com" is valid url or not. @guest271314

Comment: "valid" according to what?

Comment: i just want to validate the url without "http://" also. now it is not validating. what changes i need to do?

Comment: @guest271314. 
i just want to validate the url without "http://" also. now it is not validating. what changes i need to do?

Comment: Does `^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?` satisfy you?

Comment: Yes. @EganWolf. Thanks much.

Comment: But you are aware that this regex accepts literally everything? Even a string like "thisIsDumbRegex"...